# Arbitrary monad transformer stack in type variable

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, parametric-polymorphism

Consider the following snippet

```
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

newtype MyTransT m a = MyTransT (m a)

foo :: (MonadTrans t, Monad (t (Either e))) => MyTransT (t (Either e)) a -> a
foo = undefined

bar :: MyTransT (StateT Int (Either e)) a
bar = undefined

baz :: MyTransT (StateT Int (StateT Int (Either e))) a
baz = undefined

x = foo bar -- works

y = foo baz -- doesn't work
```

In essence, I am trying to create a function which accepts a monad transformer stack, with the top and bottom of the stack specified, while the middle can be anything.

After scratching my head for a while as to why `foo baz` was being rejected with `Couldn't match type ‘StateT Int (Either e1)’ with ‘Either e0’`, it finally occurred to me that in that case, I was assuming that `t`  was `StateT Int (StateT Int)` which is not only not a `MonadTrans`, its not properly typed/kinded.

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, or is it time to try a different approach?

Comment: Can you give some concrete examples of how you want `foo` to work in practice?

Comment: Imagine you have a type `T`, which can be thought of a container of type `V` with keys of type `K`.  Now imagine that each `V` also follows this pattern. I would like to have `foo :: StateT V (t (Either e)) a -> StateT T (ReaderT K (t (Either e))) a`. This would take stateful operations over `V` and lift them into stateful operations over `T` that have an environment with `K`. Basically a tree structure which I can extend upwards and downwards infinitely without changing existing code.

Comment: Concrete examples would be more helpful here. And feel free to put it in your question where it will be easier to read.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is about as concrete as I can get it, this isn't for a particular application or project, this is more so experimental musings. I'll see if I can find some situation in which it's actually useful.

Comment: A monad transformer stack is a _stack_. You can't specify what's at the bottom of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `foo baz` doesn't type check is because the `t` is not a transformer over the `Either e` monad - it is a transformer over the `StateT Int (Either e)` monad.

Here is how it is parsed:

```
 baz :: MyTransT (StateT Int (StateT Int (Either e))) a
                  \________/ \_____________________/
                       t            m                 a
```

Note that `m` is *not* of the form `Either e`.

You could create a new transformer, e.g. `StateTIntStateTInt`, and write
baz like this:

```
 baz :: MyTransT (StateTIntStateInt (Either e)) a
```

and then it would type check. For instance:

```
type StateTIntStateTInt = StateT (Int,Int)

baz' :: MyTransT (StateTIntStateTInt (Either e)) a
baz' = undefined

test = foo baz'
```

However, even if you work around the type issues I doubt you are going
to be able to write the function `foo`. Consider what should be returned
for this specific value of `bar`:

```
bar0 :: MyTransT (StateT Int (Either String)) Int
bar0 = MyTransT $ lift $ Left "blather"
```

What Int value should `foo bar0` return?

Comment: I realize this, and even point it out in the question. The point was that `foo` should be able to accept an arbitrary stack of transformers, hence creating a newtype for every possibility seems unlikely. also, `foo`'s return type is a placeholder, the snippet was only to demonstrate the problem. In reality, `foo` would return a value related to `t (Either e)`